# Trigger NOTIFY only on points that are in a certain PostGIS region

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I would like to trigger `NOTIFY` only on points that are in a certain `PostGIS` region. I have a table called `car`. I want to get a `NOTIFY`cation every time a car updates it's coordinate or a new car is updated, but only in a certain region. Essentially I want to monitor for changes in rows that have a point that is located in the region of my interest.

I would be grateful for any hints in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you should follow a method like this,

1- fist of all you create a "view" which is return boolean value if your point of car and region interacts with each other. For this st_contains or st_intersects function be useful.

2- Create a trigger on the car table and the trigger should run every action of update or insert.

3- The trigger affects rows just be returned of the first view that you make

this might not be the best way but I think it can solve your situation.